# Disable a date range in lightning datepicker

Tags: lightning-web-components, date-picker

I am trying to add a `lightning datepicker` on visualforce by using this `<lightning-input type="date"/>` component. It works fine and it shows the calendar but now I want to allow the user to only select a specific range of dates, say Sept 10, 2020, to Nov 20, 2020. This is also possible by using min and max attributes: `<lightning-input type="date" min="2020-09-10" max="2020-11-20" />`. Ideally, the user should not be allowed to select any date outside this range. Here, any date outside this range is greyed out, but the issue is, user can **still select that**. When they select a date that is not allowed, the component shows an error message saying `"Select Sept 10, 2020, or a date after that"`. While this is perfectly fine, I want to absolutely disable the dates outside the specified range, so that, users are not able to choose it at all.
Can someone mention any solution?

[image: lightning input (type date)]

Answer (score 0):

well, as you already noticed, the lightning-input component won't allow you to do this. The alternative?

Code your own using the slds blueprints as a reference and add your own custom logic. If you need a head start, for reference purposes, you can have a look at a sample lwc date picker I coded a while back:

https://github.com/gminero/lwcLabs

its not perfect, but it will give you a general idea of what needs to be done.

[image]